# JGitflow tasks disappear after creating hotfix branch

Tags: git, gradle, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I'm having an issue where I am able to initialize JGitflow and create a hotfix branch, however when I am on that branch, the JGitflow tasks disappear! If I try and 'publish' or 'finish' a branch I am told that the command is not available. If I check the available tasks using *./gradlew tasks* I can also see that the JGitflow tasks are no longer there. Also, if I check using the IntelliJ plugin for JGitflow, I can see that the project is on a hotfix branch (created by a JGitflow command), however there are no Gitflow options to choose from. Does anyone know what might be going on here?~

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to just make a branch, change to the version of gradle there first, then after the commit try and using the new jgitflow tasks to create hotfix branch.